# Does Islam clash with the "Do whatever you want" ideology?

Tags: islamic-philosophy

I always hear Islam is oppressive from many non-Muslims as people say it oppresses women or people arent free to do what they want. Of course being free to what you want to do has limitations but does Islam clash with the general idea that submission to God clashes with the idea of being free to do what you want and what does Islam say about the claims made against it about this "oppressive" nature etc?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Islam has rules. But then again, so does pretty much any ideology outside of outright anarchy.

If anyone considers being expected to follow rules as "oppressive", that says far more about that person than it does about the ideology itself.

Comment: But what is the Islam's response to this being like oppressive and stuff? Like people arent allowed to do what they want and that women have a lot less rights and stuff? What hadith or quran verses are there or are there even any?

Comment: @YakoubAli You want a response? Try "*Lakum dinukum waliya din*".

Comment: Yes but saying that is basically like saying yeah my religion is oppressive but we have our rules and you have yours. It doesnt necessarily mean justify it if you get what Im trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

First of all

Do you know what does a religion mean?

Do you know all philosophy behind Islam or other religions to reach this questions?

Quick answer:

Religion mean some rules by a complete thing (god) to guide us because there is not enough time to find best philosophy for each issue in life and you can trust these rules by prove of a religion.

And about your question:

1.Gender equality:

As we know of historical books and as Quran as Arabs were in a terrible condition of gender equality before the Islam and even after that.We should remember Islam was a help patch not a brutal way.

As everybody argue about gender equality around the world, there is no way to say womans and mans are physically equal because it is true for 75% of humans and it mean other ones are exceptions.

Main issue is about human rights and about that you can surf the Quran as base rules of Islam to find strong words about equality in this rights like politics and science.

And another question about limits.Yes, every religions bring us some rules to live till we found them logical and useful.Like every countries rules.

Sorry for poor english.

Answer (score -2):

Yes Islam have rules not guidelines. Rules are inherently attached to punishment or judgements while guidelines provide you ways (not a single way) to select from but doesn't impose judgement on you, you are free to choose your path and can even reject these guidelines based on your empirical experience and create your own gudielines. Most of the traditional wisdom around the ancient world and few of tradition in eastern world currently is based on guidelines and thus provide room for innovation, discovery and invention while once the society is closed inside set of rules, all these dies. The guidelines based society concern with direct relationship between person and reality whereas rule based society have an authority between person and reality which sets code of conduct.

Comment: Please let me know the downvote if I have written anything wrong?